# Difference between H-NMR with C$^{13}$ and C$^{13}$- NMR

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

I don't know if I am overcomplicating things but I am having trouble understanding the difference between H-NMR with  C$^{13}$ sample  and  C$^{13}$-NMR.

For example, if I have the molecule below and I am asked to sketch the H-NMR spectrum knowing that the carbons are C$^{13}$ and a C$^{13}$-NMR spectrum, what is the difference? For the C$^{13}$-spectrum I know that I should look at the neighbouring carbons and apply the $n+1$ rule and then look at the neighbouring hydrogens of the carbon of interest. For example, the C$^α$ has two neighbouring carbons so is split into a triplet and it also has one neighbouring hydrogen so those triplets are split into doublets making the C$^α$ show up as a multiplet of six.

[image]

However, if it is a H-spectrum with C$^{13}$ what do I look at? The correct spectrum is added below and the chemical shifts are: 
[image]

So for H$^α$ I should get $2 *5 $ peaks. Which I get from H$^α$ having one carbon neighbour (spliting it into a doublet) and then having four neighbouring hydrogens (spliting each doublet into a multiplet of five). Is that the correct way of doing it? It works for H$^β$ as well but then for the H$^N$ am I only looking at the hydrogens again (so $n+1=1+1=2$ a doublet)?

[image]

Comment: Do you understand why the $n+1$ rule works and, perhaps more importantly, when it *doesn't*? The $n+1$ "rule" is extremely inadequate for solving this question.

Comment: The H-N has a $^3J$ coupling to C. Ten Hz or so sounds, well, reasonable. The next hydrogen would be a $^4J$, so likely not visible.